# How do I read where a Windows shortcut links to in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, windows-shortcut

Node's built-in `fs` has a `fs.readLink` function, but it appears to be for symbolic links/junctions. How can I read the properties of a Windows shortcut (a  `.lnk` file), to find out where it leads?

For example: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Adobe Animate CC 2019.lnk` leads to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Animate.exe`. But how can I read the `.lnk` file to find out where the link leads?

I found `exif-parser`, but that module only works for image metadata in the exif format, which it appears .lnk files do not use.

Comment: Can you open the .lnk file to see if it’s a text formatted file?

Comment: If you mean opening it in a text editor, yes I have; the .lnk files use some sort of encoding that isn't readable by a text editor.

Comment: If you're asking to learn about the file format, [here you go](https://github.com/libyal/liblnk/blob/master/documentation/Windows%20Shortcut%20File%20(LNK)%20format.asciidoc). If you're requesting a _tool_ to do this for you, your question is off-topic here.

Comment: This file has hex codes to specify data and 0x0001 is most probably what you are looking for.